# Add popup window (html page) in form of infopath

Tags: sharepoint, popup, infopath, infopath2010

Using InfoPath Designer 2013. I need to find the way to show popup widow (some information of html page) on clicking on button or on hover the cursor on a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have popup in InfoPath.
You could simulate some when hitting a button go to other view and make there possible to back to original screen.